# VB read line by line, compare a value and extract portion to display

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I have a text file on drive C:, I need to open and read the first line and do the code to display, then read second line and do same, etc. etc. until it reads all the lines in the text file.
Not sure how to do it...

My code

I think I figure it out, below, BUT how do i do that For EACH line of the text file, meaning, apply the same evaluation per line?

```
    'type of message triggers
    Dim type1 As String = "d1err./"
    Dim type2 As String = "d1jam./"
    Dim type3 As String = "d1spe./"
    Dim type4 As String = "d2err./"
    Dim type5 As String = "d2jam./"
    Dim type6 As String = "d2spe./"

    Dim fileReader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\A\data\display.txt")
    Dim stringReader As String = fileReader.ReadLine()

    While stringReader <> Nothing
        Dim LineStart As String = stringReader.Substring(0, 7)
        Dim RestOfLine As String = stringReader.Substring(7)

        If LineStart = type1 Then
            Display1.Dis1RTB1.Clear()
            Display1.Dis1RTB1.Text = RestOfLine
        ElseIf LineStart = type2 Then
            Display1.Dis1RTB2.Clear()
            Display1.Dis1RTB2.Text = RestOfLine
        ElseIf LineStart = type3 Then
            Display1.Dis1RTB3.Clear()
            Display1.Dis1RTB3.Text = RestOfLine
        ElseIf LineStart = type4 Then
            Display2.Dis2RTB1.Clear()
            Display2.Dis2RTB1.Text = RestOfLine
        ElseIf LineStart = type5 Then
            Display2.Dis2RTB2.Clear()
            Display2.Dis2RTB2.Text = RestOfLine
        ElseIf LineStart = type6 Then
            Display2.Dis2RTB3.Clear()
            Display2.Dis2RTB3.Text = RestOfLine
        End If
        stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
    End While
    fileReader.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: It won't solve the problem, but you may find your coding easier if you use a [Select...Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx). For reading the file, you will need a *loop*, for example using the [While...End While Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx), which might start with `While Not stringReader.EndOfStream`.

Comment: The text in (what I assume are) the TextBoxes will be overwritten if there is more than one "LineStart" of "type1", and so on. If that is not the intended behaviour, you could use the [.AppendText Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
Public Class Form1
Dim fileReader As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Text Document.txt")
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not fileReader.EndOfStream Then
        TextBox1.Text += fileReader.ReadLine & vbNewLine
    End If

    'Or you could do it like this

    While Not fileReader.EndOfStream
        Dim tmpStr As String = fileReader.ReadLine
        Select Case tmpStr
            Case "Dis1err"
                'Do Work here
        End Select
    End While
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: i edited the code i was using, but now, i am not sure how to apply that to EACH line in the txt file...

Comment: Do you know the line order ?

Comment: 1> d1err./ error on ZZZZZ, 
2> d1jam./ 
3> d1spe./ rest of system ok
4> d2err./
5> d2jam./ jam in area YYYY
6> d2spe./ system maint req